# How to finding xpath with multiple contains conditions

Tags: css, xpath, selenium-ide

there is a table in td that can find the link or plugin icon. The image of this cell can be as [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oeRKD.png).

The xpath I want to find is only the cell with the link icon.
How can I find XPath that will give that cell because the "Password Security" cell, which is the photos above, has only the link icon?

[Table Css here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gdh3Z.png)

When I tried the following code,[it gave the cell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nIT5h.png), which is both the link and the plugin icon.

```
//table[@id='DataTables_Table_1']//tbody//td//i[contains(@class,'fa fa-link') and not(contains(@class,'fa-paperclip'))]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a solution for me to list the cells that do not contain the plugin icon and have icon.

```
//table[@id='DataTables_Table_1']//td[3][not(i[contains(@class,'fa-paperclip')]) and (i)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use :

```
//table//td[not(self::td[i[contains(@class,'fa-paperclip')]])]
```

Output : Password Security node

Or less secure :

```
//table//td[count(./i)=1 and i[@class="fa fa-link mailIcon"]]
```

Output : Password Security node

Why don't you use the classic form and search for text ? :

```
//table//td[text()[1][contains(.,"Password Security")]]
```

Output : Password Security node